# How to put the contents of a 32 bit register in a byte array?

Tags: c, cpu-registers

How to put the contents of a 32 bit CPU register in a byte array?

Comment: You can't do this in C. There are no registers in C.

Comment: I have some value to be put in a character array which is present in a CPU register(32-bit). Is there no way to do this?

Comment: You will need to use assembly or non-standard compiler extensions for that. Without knowing your compiler/environment, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: I am using Visual c++ 8.0 compiler in windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to write inline assembly to read contents of some register. For example - to read ESP register into some int variable (Windows & Visual Studio) - you would do something like this:

```
int stackpointer = 0;
    __asm {
        mov stackpointer, esp
    }
    printf("stack pointer: %i\n", stackpointer);
```